# To find the equation whose roots are some function of roots of another given equation.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, roots

Consider the equation $$f(x)= x^{2020}+ 23x^{2018} + 7 \text{.}$$ This has roots $a_i : i=1,2,\dots,2020$. Another polynomial $P(x)$ of the degree same as $f(x)$ is such that
$$P(a_i + 1/a_i ) = 0$$ for all $a_i$. Find the value of $$\sqrt{(388 \cdot P(0))/P(-1)}\ \text{.}$$

My Approach :

$$X = a_i + 1/a_i$$

$$(a_i)^2 -xa_i +1 = 0$$

$$a_i = \left(x+{\sqrt{x^2 - 4}}\right)/2 $$  Or

$$a_i = \left(x-{\sqrt{x^2 - 4}}\right)/2$$

Replacing the first value of $a_i$ in place of $x$ in $f(x)$ one obtains $P(x)$ which gives $P(0) = -1$ and $P(-1) = 22w^2 + 6$ where $w$ is a complex cube root of unity.

Concern : The expected answer is an integer. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I have no idea how you're deducing $P(0)$ or $P(-1)$. For one thing, you can multiply $P(x)$ by any non-zero constant without altering the defining properties, so it's not unique and only the quotient $P(0)/P(-1)$ would be uniquely determined.

Comment: Pls note that f(x) and P(x) are polynomial , not polynomial written as equation with RHS =0. This ensures that one cannot multiply non zero arbitrary constants on both sides

Comment: Your comment makes no sense to me unfortunately. All we know about $P(x)$ is that it has degree 2020 and for every root $a_i$ of $f(x)$, we have that $a_i + 1/a_i$ is a root of $P(x)$. These two conditions are unaffected by replacing $P(x)$ with $cP(x)$ for any non-zero complex number $c$.

Comment: Related: [Evaluate $P(1)/P(-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500547/evaluate-p1-p-1). See also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h162509p906717 and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h625792p3751954.